# Kubernetes DNS getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN problem

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I have A Git/Jenkins/Kubernetes Pipeline setup, where I have a simple NodeJS app, where I am Fetching GET request + Axios web scraper + Discord bot. (that is a function which is on repeat every 15 minutes)

When I run this app Directly on Docker, or Directly in IntelliJ it works, I can leave it for 30 minutes and it works as it Should.

Problems start at Kubernetes, where Pod is Created and it is Running, and usually few Interval works, All API requests return result, Discord message is shown, and after some time pod restarts itself with a NodeJS

error:

```
ed in as myapp#692! node:internal/process/promises:265 triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */); ^

<ref *1> Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN vechainstats.com at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:72:26) { errno: -3001, code: 'EAI_AGAIN', syscall: 'getaddrinfo', hostname: 'vechainstats.com', config: { transitional: { silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false }, adapter: [Function: httpAdapter], transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ], transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ], timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', maxContentLength: -1, maxBodyLength: -1, validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus], headers: { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /', 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.26.1'
```

I tried on two Kubernetes clusters, Clearly, this is a DNS issue, but I have no clue where to start to solve this.

Any ideas?

I tried this on standalone Docker, where it Works. It also works directly in IDEA.

On two Kubernetes clusters, it doesn't work without this error and pods restarting.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was, to change the code API requests to "await" and I double-checked metallb load balancer, and I had the wrong network configuration.

Now, pod won't restart anymore.